# How to assign checkbox on DataGrid row headers from code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, checkbox

In my WPF application I create Datagrid dynamically from code behind. However, I want to have a datagrid with check boxes on row header similar to **[this](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/11/multiselect-datagrid-with-checkboxes/).**

I know how to do it from XML, but not from cs code. Is there any idea how to handle this situation?
ps. my code is very big I cannot put it here but if you need more info, please put comments below. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
var dg = new DataGrid();

var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();

var gridFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
var checkboxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
checkboxFactory.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("IsSelected") { RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor,typeof(DataGridRow),1)});
gridFactory.AppendChild(checkboxFactory);

dataTemplate.VisualTree = gridFactory;
dg.RowHeaderTemplate = dataTemplate;
```

Hopefully this should be able to be put into your code without too much effort, probably just have to change the `DataGrid` name from "dg".

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. I do this with the XamlReader class because the FrameworkElementFactory class is now deprecated.